# Как объявить Си функцию с переменным числом параметров в Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, функции, varargs

При переводе функций с С на Delphi столкнулся с интересным моментом, в заголовочном файле на С, есть вот такое объявление функции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как правильно объявить эту функцию на Delphi (мой вариант, только первых два параметра) ?

```
function Vix_GetProperties(handle: VixHandle;
                           firstPropertyID: VixPropertyID
                           ): VixError; cdecl; external 'vix.dll';
```

К сожалению, не нашел примеров, как переносить такие вещи `...` как параметр из С на Delphi.

Comment: Попробуй погуглить `varargs delphi`, но насколько я понял, оно существует только для вызова внешних функций, написанных на си, а в самом делфи такую функцию не объявишь.

Comment: https://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=378728

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если верить [этому источнику](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/c3/518042.html), объявление должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
function Vix_GetProperties(
  handle: VixHandle;
  firstPropertyID: VixPropertyID
): VixError; cdecl varargs; external 'vix.dll';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! То что нужно!

Comment: Всё так, но лучше верить официальной документации: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#External_Declarations

Comment: @zed, ещё бы она гуглилась...